# How to subscribe to a topic in firebase cloud messaging from device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do I subscribe to topics on firebase on from a device,
Earlier it used to be as simple as

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
}
```

now the function has changed to

```
public TopicManagementResponse subscribeToTopic(@NonNull List<String> registrationTokens,
      @NonNull String topic) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
    return subscribeOp(registrationTokens, topic).call();
  }
```

where there is an extra param with registration tokens...
How do I subscribe to a topic from a device with the latest code ??

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that second function call from, but the documentation still shows `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic

Comment: I just crtl+clicked into the function... anyhow let me check my dependencies and get back to you

Comment: I am using firebase bom 28.4.1
here is how it looks like
https://ibb.co/yss8zgd

and here is the subscribetoTopicMethod in the FirebaseMessaging.java class

https://ibb.co/1TLZR4s

please help

Comment: This overload takes a list of tokens, and is part of the Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/TopicManagementResponse You should not be using that SDK in your Android app, as it would introduce a serious security risk. Instead use the regular SDK for Android, with the link I provided in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the Admin SDK for server-side Java code. This SDK should only be used in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. Using the Admin SDK in your client-side Android code is a security risk, as it allows malicious users to get administrative access to your Firebase project.

The solution is to follow the documentation for Android developers on [subscribing to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic). When you do that, the code should look like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")
```

Comment: Thank you Frank everything is working now..